# Need to redirect to HTTPS using my current htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, https

I want to redirect HTTP and www to `https://example.com`.

I tried using:

```
# force HTTPS and www.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?!^www\.)^(.+)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But the result is only `https://www.` - the domain disappeared!

My current `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# REWRITE ENGINE CONFIG
#ExpiresActive On
DirectoryIndex under_construction.html index.html index.php
#Header set Cache-Control "max-age=259200, public"
#ExpiresDefault "access plus 3 days"
#Header unset ETag
#FileETag None

# Expires header for static content
#<FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf|jgz|js.jgz)$">
#Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
#ExpiresDefault "access plus 11 months"
#</FilesMatch>

# Auth for non-public projects
#AuthName "ZEN 2.2 Login"
#AuthType Basic
#AuthUserFile /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/username/.htpasswd
#AuthUserFile F:/wamp/www/username/.htpasswd
#AuthGroupFile /dev/null
#require valid-user

# REWRITE CORE RULES RULES -- PLEASE DON'T MODIFY --
# THESE ARE THE MAIN REWRITES THAT MAKE THE ENTIRE WORLD SPIN

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

# IF NO IMAGE FOUND
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$
RewriteRule .* resources/static/images/no_image.png [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^robots.txt$ resources/static/robots.php [L]

# gZip minified js files
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.jgz -f
RewriteRule (.*)\.js$ $1\.js.jgz [L]
AddType "text/javascript" .js.jgz
AddEncoding gzip .jgz

# gZip minified css files
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.jgz -f
RewriteRule (.*)\.css$ $1\.css.jgz [L]
AddType "text/css" .css.jgz
AddEncoding gzip .jgz
</IfModule>
```

Need some help adding the redirection to HTTPS and non-WWW to the current `.htaccess` file.

The problem when using code from here -> https://gist.github.com/vielhuber/f2c6bdd1ed9024023fe4

Is that the redirection is broken, and the result is `https://www.` only, no domain name is showing.

Comment: _I want to redirect http and www to https.example.com_ are you sure you don't mean _redirect http://example.com to https://example.com_?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
# force HTTPS and www.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Some webservers don't create the `HTTPS` header when http protocol is used. So if `HTTPS` is **not** *on* (is *off* or *null*) this condition is true.

Comment: The problem with this is that the first condition will not always be successful (when HTTP + non-www is requested), so the `%1` backreference will not always be set.

Comment: The result is weird, its not redirected but it gives "This page isn’t working"

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> # force HTTPS and www.
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?!^www\.)^(.+)$ [OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
> RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
> ```

The problem with this code is, as the preceding comment suggests, it tries to redirect to `www`, not the domain apex. But it is also fundamentally flawed since the first condition is not always met (when HTTPS is *off* and www is requested), so the `%1` backreference is not always set (so the domain name is omitted from the redirect - as you have found).

If you want a *generalised* (ie. without explicitly stating the hostname) solution then you would need to do something like the following instead:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)
 RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The above rule block states... for all requests that are either for the www subdomain OR are for HTTP then redirect to HTTPS, less the www subdomain (if any) at the same URL-path.

The purpose of the 3rd condition - which must *always* match - is to simply capture the hostname less the www subdomain (if any). This is then referenced using the `%1` backreference in the `RewriteRule` *substitution*.

NB: Test with a 302 (temporary) redirect first to avoid caching issues.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

> **UPDATE:** it is redirecting to `domainname.com:443`

That shouldn't be happening with the above directives, unless perhaps the *port* is explicitly included in the request? (But is that a redirect for `http` or `https`?)

You can try changing the 3rd *condition* to read:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?([^:]+)
```

Or *hardcode* the canonical hostname, which is arguably preferable and more reliable (without knowing your system). For example:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

With this *hardcoded* solution, it cannot possibly redirect to anything other than the canonical URL - regardless of the request or system configuration.

---

> **EDIT#1:** if I remove the htaccess file completely, the website still redirect to :443 if access from https

To help with *debugging*, try the following in your `.htaccess` file and then access `https://your-domain.com/`. What happens?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

If you see a 403 Forbidden response then your web application would seem to be triggering this redirect. If not and you are still redirected then something in the main server config / virtual host would seem to be triggering the redirect.

> **EDIT#2:** Yes, the response when i browse the https is 403 Forbidden.

That would seem to suggest that your web application is triggering this redirect.

And this would seem to be further backed up by the fact that you only seem to get this malformed redirect when requesting a *valid* URL, ie. one which only the app knows about. For example, `https://example.com/contact` (a valid page) is redirecting to `http://example.com:443/contact` (ERROR), but `https://example.com/does-not-exist` does not redirect (you get an application error / 404).

Comment: That wouldn't seem possible given the directives above? (The _browser_ will also omit the protocol when requesting HTTPS + 443) Is the redirected URL with a `http` or `https` protocol? What is the URL being requested? I've updated my answer.

Comment: I tried all your suggestions but nothing worked, something weird i didnt understand why happened. If I put your last suggestion without changing the domain name example.com, the redirection worked fine, but when I replaced it with correct domain name, again i receive domainname.com:443

Comment: Just to clarify... the above canonical redirect should go near the top of the `.htaccess` file (certainly _before_ the existing mod_rewrite directives). However, that shouldn't cause the resulting redirect you are seeing. Does a direct request for `https://your-domain.com/foo` resolve OK?

Comment: I did put it above everything in the top, also clearing the cache every time. here is the domain if it give faster testing http://tiny-mighty.com/. I don't know if its ok with the rules here. and thanks for the support.

Comment: Requesting `https://tiny-mighty.com/` directly triggers a 302 redirect back to `http://tiny-mighty.com:443/` (note HTTP) - this doesn't have anything to do with the redirect above. Have you ensured that SSL cert is properly installed on the server? How is the SSL cert managed? Was `https://tiny-mighty.com/` previously accessible before trying to implement this redirect?

Comment: I analyzed the account status from the server WHM > Auto SSL, SUCCESS TLS Status: OK, Also i noticed something, if I remove the htaccess file completely, the website still redirect to :443 if access from https

Comment: So, something in either your server config or web application would seem to be triggering that erroneous redirect? Do you have access to the server config? I've updated my answer with a debugging tip.

Comment: Yes, the response when i browse the https is 403 Forbidden. I started working on this project after someone else. So you are saying the previous developer implemented a redirection somewhere in the app ?

Comment: "a redirection somewhere in the app ?" - That's what it looks like. And this would seem to be further backed up by the fact that you only seem to get this malformed redirect when requesting a valid URL - which only the app knows about. eg. `https://tiny-mighty.com/contact` redirects to `http://tiny-mighty.com:443/contact` (ERROR), but `https://tiny-mighty.com/does-not-exist` does not redirect.